# How to add last row to UITableView with smooth scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm building chat interface using UITableView. i'm adding cells using below code

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.messageCards.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .bottom)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

and after adding i'm using scrollToRowAtIndexPath to show last inserted row.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.messageCards.count - 1, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

but at the end both animation are mixing and scrolling not happening smoothly.

Comment: What should be the desired sequence of animation..

Comment: @RohitKP first i want to scroll up and want to show new message using animation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I have tested the code:

```
    arrayData.addObject(str)
    let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: arrayData.count-1, inSection: 0)

    tblView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexpath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    tblView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexpath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
```

Following is output: let me know if you want complete source.

[image]

Comment: This works fine when the size of the cells being added is fixed, when a large cell is added in between, the animation gets messed up, and the entire tableview flashes and the scrolling is not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this.

```
 [UITableView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.messageCards.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"animated");
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:self.messageCards.count-1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.messageCards addObject:@"DATA Whatever you want"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.messageCards.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its wonder, but to achieve smooth adding when scrolling just need to call reloadData()

```
func fetchNext(_ countToFetch: Int? = 10) {

    let existingCount = items?.count ?? 0

    networkService?.items(bySkip: existingCount, take: countToFetch, completion: { (data, error) in

        if let newItems = data?.items() as? [Element], newItems.count > 0 {
            self.items?.append(contentsOf: newItems)
            self.refreshCallback?()
        }
    })
}
```

Callback is:

```
datasource?.refreshCallback = { [weak self] in

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self?.table.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
    self?.table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `reloadData` will mess things up even more in my opinion, as all the rows will be reloaded, which is not required.